# htaccess redirect to subfolder and file

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I think there are many htaccess redirect samples but I can't find a case similar to mine.

I have many sub folder my root

```
/suppliers
 |- /suppliers/abc
 |- /suppliers/xyz

/merchants
 |- /merchants/abc
 |- /merchants/xzy
```

etc.

I want to redirect them when I type

```
/m/yyy -> /merchants/yyy/index.php
/m/yyy/abc -> /m/merchants/yyy/abc.php
/m/yyy/abc/ -> /m/merchants/yyy/abc/index.php
```

Can anyone advise me on how I can do that?

Comment: Maybe like? RewriteRule ^m/yyy$ /merchants/yyy/index.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}

Comment: I prefer yyy is not the string hardcode in the htaccess, yyy in my case is just a sample

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: I tried
RewriteRule ^m/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,15})/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,15})$ /merchants/$1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^m/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,15})$ /merchants/$1/index.php [L]

When I type https://example.com/m/abc or /m/abc/xyz, it successfully redirect to https://example.com/merchants/abc/index.php or /m/abc/xyz.php but I doesn't work if http://example.com/m/abc/

Comment: please post this code by editing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# /m/yyy rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/?$ merchants/$1/index.php [L,NC]

# /m/yyy/abc rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ merchants/$1/$2.php [L,NC]

# /m/yyy/abc/ rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ merchants/$1/$2/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: It works for me, may I know how the [\w-]+ function?

Comment: It matches a letter or digit or hyphen